# Disable alt text in firefox

Tags: macos, firefox

Is there a way to disable alt text to appear when an image is loading in firefox ?  
 I Hate it when my connection is slower to see the text before the image.

Comment: Perhaps _increasing_ the rendering delay to half a second will decrease the level of annoyance for you. [lifehacker - ff tweak rendering delay](http://lifehacker.com/287107/tweak-firefoxs-rendering-settings)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the *tooltip* or `TITLE` text you can open `about:config` and toggle the setting `browser.chrome.toolbar_tips`. This will prevent tooltips from showing.